# Do we need the [needle] and [haystack] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are [26 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/needle+or+haystack) tagged [needle](/questions/tagged/needle) or [haystack](/questions/tagged/haystack). Lots of the questions refer to the [php strpos function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or other similar php functions which use `$needle` and `$haystack` as argument names in the documentation.

Other uses include:

- Displaying a gauge with a needle.
- Django haystack library - should use [django-haystack](/questions/tagged/django-haystack)

I do not think these tags add any useful information and they should be burninated (with 1 or 2 questions retagged to [django-haystack](/questions/tagged/django-haystack) as needed).

Comment: They do not seem to be necessary for any of those questions. They are also never the only tag used. *Burninate* imo.

Comment: Finding a needle when you knew it was in a haystack was bad enough. Now one can't even find the haystack!? Oh my...